# How do you disable input value on web form field / input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

How do you disable the autocomplete functionality in the major browsers for a specific input (or form field)?

```
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control" data-required="true" value="<?php echo $_POST['fullname']?>" >
```

When I open this form I see the value in this input even if I didn't insert any value.

Comment: You are setting the value with your php echo statement.

Comment: no, its show me value when click submit, but before click submit its show me value, its must be empty

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but $_POST['fullname'] will be the value of the form when it's submitted so if you type something in and submit, it will keep that value in the form.

Comment: If you are saying it should not have a value.... YOU ARE SETTING THE VALUE! If you do not want a value to be there, do not set it.

Comment: i remove it and still show value

Comment: Remove value="<?php echo $_POST['fullname']?>" from your code and see if that does what you want.

Comment: If you removed the value attribute, you may have a browser plugin or something automatically filling in the form.

Comment: i do that but still error

Comment: Browser by default set value for your textbox?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the autocomplete attribute:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

> "This would be useful when a text input is one-off and unique. Like a
>   CAPTCHA input, one-time use codes, or for when you have built your own
>   auto-suggest/auto-complete feature and need to turn off the browser
>   default."

Source : [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/)

Comment: i do that but sitl have value

Answer (score 3):

I think adding `autocomplete="off"` would get you an error on most browsers, furthermore, `autocomplete="off"` is an invalid property.

Try to check the [Mozilla Developer Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)  instead.

Comment: @khalidahmed you can try putting autocomplete="off" in your form tag too

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random string using javasript or php and add it to the end of an input `name`, maybe even use a delimiter to split it apart from the actual `name`.

In php, you could use something like the `session_id` for this and simply `echo` it to the end of the `name`.

`<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="example<?php echo "," . session_id()?>">`

You can replace the `","` with any delimiter of your choice, so long as it isn't alphanumeric. Then when processing the data submitted, you can remove it from the end of the actual `name` of the input field.

With a field `name` always being different, your browser cant autocomplete it.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/218453/12251360

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" 
          autocomplete="off" action="http://www.example.com/form.cgi">
```

This will work in Internet Explorer and Mozilla FireFox, the downside is that it is not XHTML standard.

> Solution 2

The solution for Chrome is to add `autocomplete="new-password"` to the input type password.

Example:

```
<form name="myForm"" method="post">
     <input name="user" type="text" />
     <input name="pass" type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Chrome always autocomplete the data if it finds a box of *type password*, just enough to indicate for that box `autocomplete = "new-password"`.

**This works well for me.**

Note: make sure with F12 that your changes take effect, many times browsers save the page in cache, this gave me a bad impression that it did not work, but the browser did not actually bring the changes.

> Solution 3

```
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" data-required="true" value="<?php echo $_POST['fullname']?>"  >
```

**links**

Solution 3 Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496311/6923146

Solution 2 Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40791726/6923146